# Panning in Direct sound wthout using SetPan function

Tags: c++, sound

I was wondering if it is possible to pan a WAV file in direct sound without using the SetPan function. If so how?

That is change the volume on 2 different speakers, right and left, to simulate that the sound is moving around the player.

Comment: Is there any good reason to not use SetPan? Maybe we can help you with that.

Comment: It's a school project... we are not allowed to use setpan, we are supposed to do this manually by changing the volume on the speakers correctly to simulate a 3D atmosphere

Comment: We're not here to give the answer to your school exercises and the questions has no relevance for others.

Comment: Yep, panning involves changing the speakers' volumes. That's... kind of all there is to it. What exactly are you having trouble with?